# Mysql FIND_IN_SET GET ALL Column

Tags: mysql

I have two table Roles and Normal,

I want get list of values from Normal if Role ID exists. In the output result I am not getting all the results. Value 60 is missing.

Table Roles

| id | value_col | project |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 60 | 80 |
| 2 | 40 | 80 |
| 3 | 100 | 80 |

Table Normal

| id | role_id | project | status |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 90 | 1 |
| 2 | 1 | 80 | NULL |
| 3 | 2,3 | 80 | NULL |

Expected Result

| value_col |
| --- |
| 60 |
| 40 |
| 100 |

MyQuery

select Roles.value_col  from Roles join Normal AS n ON n.project_id = Roles.project FIND_IN_SET(Roles.id,  Normal.role_id) > '0') and Normal  is NULL

it should list 60

Output I am getting is 60  in the output result

| value_col |
| --- |
| 40 |
| 100 |

Please tell me to list all the values that exists in Normal

here is the DB link

When Status is NULl still listing 60 value it is not correct

[DB Link](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/7k6B3yo72YSReBeHX2x134/1)

[1](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/7k6B3yo72YSReBeHX2x134/1):
I have two table Roles and Normal,

I want get list of values from Normal if Role ID exists. In the output result I am  getting all the results. Value 60 is also. but porject 80 only  need to list

Table Roles

| id | value_col | project |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 60 | 80 |
| 2 | 40 | 80 |
| 3 | 100 | 80 |

Table Normal

| id | role_id | project | status |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 90 | 1 |
| 2 | 1 | 80 | NULL |
| 3 | 2,3 | 80 | NULL |

Expected Result

| value_col |
| --- |
| 60 |
| 40 |
| 100 |

MyQuery

select Roles.value_col  from Roles join Normal AS n ON n.project_id = Roles.project FIND_IN_SET(Roles.id,  Normal.role_id) > '0') and Normal  is NULL

But I am not get value 60 in the output result

| value_col |
| --- |
| 60 |
| 40 |
| 100 |

Please tell me to list all the values that exists in Normal

here is the DB link
[DB Link](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/7k6B3yo72YSReBeHX2x134/1)

Comment: Fix your data model!  Storing numbers in strings is a bad idea.  Storing multiple columns in a string is a bad idea.

Comment: Sure this is to test only

Comment: I just ran your dbfiddle, and it does return all three values 60, 40, 100. How is this not what you say you want?

Comment: No I update the query it should not list 60 now. Still listing

Comment: Okay I  need to check

Comment: @aRvi  is working I need to check

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A simple join will work with `FIND_IN_SET`:

```
SELECT Roles.value_col FROM Roles 
JOIN Normal ON Normal.project_id = Roles.project 
AND FIND_IN_SET(Roles.id, Normal.role_id) AND Normal.status IS NULL
```

Check this for reference:

https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/7k6B3yo72YSReBeHX2x134/0

The `status` is `NULL` for all 3 rold_ids. So it will return 3 results.

[image]

Comment: No it is no working.I have updated the  query https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/7k6B3yo72YSReBeHX2x134/2

Comment: @BLPraveen I have attached the screenshot, it is showing the result. Can you tell, what is not working?

Comment: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/7k6B3yo72YSReBeHX2x134/4

Comment: I have updated the query when Null should not select 60 value still listing

Comment: ('1', '1', '80',NULL),
  ('2', '2,3', '80',NUll); it is null for all 3 values 1,2,3

Comment: if you want that 60 value should not be there then you need to make the status of that row non null value.